# Not getting the layout I want in the nav code with CSS Grid i want it to take upp the hole width

Tags: html, css

I use grids to customise my html layout and it does not work as I want. I want my `nav` to take all available width.

Here is my code:

```css
  header {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: header;
  border: solid;
}

#nav1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: MH;
  width: 1fr;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: MC;
  width: 1frs;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav3 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: start;
  width: 1fr;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: solid;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 100px;
}

main {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-area: main;
  height: 500px;
  color: #ff00eb;
  border-color: black;
}

aside {
  width: 0.5fr;
  border: solid;
  background-color: purple;
  grid-area: aside;
}

#big-container,
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'MH MC start' 'main main aside' 'footer footer footer ';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
```

```html
<!-- detta är min header-->
<header>
  <h1></h1>
</header>

<div id="big-container">

  <nav>
    <a href="Mitt-hus-(6)/index.html" id="nav1"> mitt hus</a>
    <a href="kalender/calender.html" id="nav2"> min calender</a>
    <a href="index2.0.html" id="nav3">main</a>
  </nav>

  <main>

    main
  </main>


  <aside>
    aside
  </aside>


  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `a` tags seem to work just fine. What are you hoping it does?

Comment: yes that is what i want it to do

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version (in terms of code) of what you wanna achieve:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav nav nav" "main main aside" "footer footer footer ";
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: header;
  border: solid;
}
nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
#nav1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav3 {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-area: main;
  height: 500px;
  color: #ff00eb;
  border-color: black;
}

aside {
  width: 0.5fr;
  border: solid;
  background-color: purple;
  grid-area: aside;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: solid;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>

<nav>
  <a href="Mitt-hus-(6)/index.html" id="nav1"> mitt hus</a>
  <a href="kalender/calender.html" id="nav2"> min calender</a>
  <a href="index2.0.html" id="nav3">main</a>
</nav>

<main>
  main
</main>

<aside>
  aside
</aside>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assign to the nav bar the display flex attribute. Like that:

```css
 header {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: header;
  border: solid;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: solid;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 100px;
}

main {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-area: main;
  height: 500px;
  color: #ff00eb;
  border-color: black;
}

aside {
  width: 0.5fr;
  border: solid;
  background-color: purple;
  grid-area: aside;
}

#big-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'MH MC start' 'main main aside' 'footer footer footer ';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {  
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid;  
  text-align: center;      
  width:100%;
}

nav > a:nth-child(1) {  
  background-color: green;
}
nav > a:nth-child(2) {  
  background-color: green;
}
nav > a:nth-child(3) {  
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- detta är min header-->
<header>
  <h1></h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <a href="Mitt-hus-(6)/index.html" id="nav1"> mitt hus</a>
  <a href="kalender/calender.html" id="nav2"> min calender</a>
  <a href="index2.0.html" id="nav3">main</a>
</nav>

<div id="big-container">
  <main>

    main
  </main>


  <aside>
    aside
  </aside>


  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```